# Dynamic email template to different email clients - PHP

Tags: php, email, email-client

I have been searching for answer for a while but i could not find one direct answer.

I am working on a news letter module for a web application built in PHP. Application sends large amounts of emails to  users. I need a way to send different email templates based on device/client user uses to read  the email. especially mobile clients.

At least I want to distinguish desktop and mobile versions. Is there a way for this.

Comment: How do you intend to actually target email clients?  Emails are not aware of the client.  I can view my emails in no less than four different clients with four vastly different capabilities.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word no. HTML emails are handled by the email provider itself. Gmail (for example) as a provider will show content to the end user regardless of the device you are using.

That said if you design your template well enough to be considered "responsive" you can spoof your idea by having automagically shrinking tables.

Also no email provider allows javascript in templates for security reasons and very few allow full CSS rules and only support basic CSS 2.

Answer (score 3):

Isn't Possible. You can't even use javascript to detect the client as far as I know.

Comment: yep I know we cant use any script in the email templates. just wondered if there is a way. Thanks